# error in activating virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv, virtualbox, vagrant

I got this error when I tried to activate my virtual env
i.e. source ~/edu-venv/bin/activate

```
-bash: /home/vagrant/edu-venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

what should I do ?

few hours back when I did vagrant halt I got this error

```
c:\Django\sites\vagrant>vagrant halt
[default] Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["showvminfo", "507b7f20-3a71-40bd-90e6-63ecde326ccd", "--machinereadable"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005), callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "COMGETTER(RemoteUSBDevices)(ComSafeArrayAsOutParam(coll))" at line 1840 of fi
le VBoxManageInfo.cpp
```

But then I immediately did vagrant up and it started and did vagrant halt it stopped gracefully then I shut down my pc. Now its not working

Comment: does the file exist ? if you do `ls /home/vagrant/edu-venv/bin/activate` what do you get ?

Comment: nope it gives this ls: cannot access /home/vagrant/edu-venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory. What should I do to get it back.

Comment: @karthikr is there any solution to fix this

Comment: create a new virtual env..  `virtualenv ~/edu-env`

Comment: @karthikr And I can access my current project in it ??

Comment: yes you should be able to

Answer (score 1):

If you already are in your virtual-env, then you need to come out of it, in order to activate your environment.
 If you are somewhere here-

```
 $-home/vagrant/edu-venv
```

Then,you need to come out of that directory. 
Go to this instead -

```
 $-home/vagrant/
```

and, then try running your command -

```
 $-home/vagrant source edu-venv/bin/activate
```

Hope, this helps!

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1 - Creat a new virtual environment in your project directory ('myproject')**

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
virtualenv venv
```

**Step 2 - Activate the corresponding environment**

For Linux/OS X:

```
venv/bin/activate
```

For Windows:

```
venv\scripts\activate
```